# Maven dependency versioning and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have a Java project X has dependency (in pom file) on project Y.

I was modifying in Y and build X,Y with Maven tool then runing X (on JBoss) without problems.

When I added new class in Y then building with Maven (without problems), then running X, it throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for the new class.

I think its a Maven dependency versioning or something like that ... I searched mainly at Google but nothing has effect... How to resolve this problem??

Comment: I noted that the produced x.jar did NOT has a "lib" directory containing y.jar ... I added this manually ... and it's running fine ... but now, How make Maven do that automatically (in case this is a correct solution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry for late info.

The X package is ejb, so the X.jar has no lib directory.

Then Y.jar should be placed in the Jboss/server/default/lib, it worked correctly.

Thanx for all.

Answer (score 7):

Moro, you wrote in a comment that X has the following dependency declared:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>Y</groupId>
  <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

First point. You are using a "fixed" version here (as opposed to "`SNAPSHOT`"). When using `SNAPSHOT`, maven will automatically grab the latest `SNAPSHOT` **every time** you build. On the other hand, when you are using 1.0, once maven has downloaded this artifact, it **never** tries to get a new 1.0. So, you should increment Y's version or, if Y is under active development (enhancements, bug fixes, etc), you should really use `SNAPSHOT`.
For more informations about `SNAPSHOT`, check out the chapter [9.3.1.2. SNAPSHOT Versions](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-relationships-sect-snapshot-versions) of Sonatype's book:

> Why would you use this? SNAPSHOT
>   versions are used for projects under
>   active development. If your project
>   depends on a software component that
>   is under active development, you can
>   depend on a SNAPSHOT release, and
>   Maven will periodically attempt to
>   download the latest snapshot from a
>   repository when you run a build.
>   Similarly, if the next release of your
>   system is going to have a version
>   "1.4", your project would have a
>   version "1.4-SNAPSHOT" until it was
>   formally released.

Second point. You are using a `provided` scope. According to the chapter 
[9.4.1. Dependency Scope](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-dependency-scope):

> `provided` dependencies are used when
>   you expect the JDK or a container to
>   provide them. For example, if you were
>   developing a web application, you
>   would need the Servlet API available
>   on the compile classpath to compile a
>   servlet, but you wouldn’t want to
>   include the Servlet API in the
>   packaged WAR; the Servlet API  JAR is
>   supplied by your application server or
>   servlet container. `provided`
>   dependencies are available on the
>   compilation classpath (not runtime).
>   They are not transitive, nor are they
>   packaged.

Is this really what you want? How are you deploying X and Y on JBoss? Shouldn't you use the default `compile` scope?

Comment: I just used <dependency>
       <groupId>Y</groupId>
    <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency> 
but it didn't put lib directory and not running

Comment: that is because you need to change the versionnumber in Y to 1.0-SNAPSHOT and then run mvn install. after that, the correct dependency is available

Comment: @Moro Without more details about your maven modules (packaging, versions...), it's hard to guess what is exactly happening. What kind of J2EE module is X? What kind of packaging are you using in your pom.xml? Could you provide your pom.xml files?

Comment: you both updated the version number in Y\pom.xml and the reference to it in X\pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `mvn install` on Y after adding the new class?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install/deploy the new version of Y, upgrade X's dependencies for the new Y version, and re-build X?

Comment: the Y pom has version <version>1.0</version> and the X pom has the dependency as <dependency>  <groupId>Y</groupId>  <artifactId>Y</artifactId>  <scope>provided</scope>  <version>1.0</version>  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **mvn clean** on project Y before you built it?

Comment: yes clean then install for Y ... and clean then package for X

Answer (score 0):

Maven resolves dependencies from local and remote repositories, though IDE plugins such as [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) will also resolve dependencies that are projects within the workspace. If you don't have  such a plugin, you will need to install artifact Y to a local repository or deploy it to a remote repository so that you and your peers can access it before Maven will recognise that a change has been made when building project X.

[workspace resolution screenshot http://docs.codehaus.org/download/attachments/11403480/project-properties.png](http://docs.codehaus.org/download/attachments/11403480/project-properties.png)

If the two projects are closely related, you could consider creating a [multi-module build](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/multimodule.html) so that projects X and Y are built at the same time.

Comment: 1. It is in repository, such that i use install command             2. It already a multi-module project ... and I tried to build it within the parent project ... but the same thing